# Reorder parts of URL path to put date together using .htaccess redirects

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress

#### old permalink:

`https://www.example.com/2019/cat/subcat/10/25/post-name/amp/`

#### new permalink:

`https://www.example.com/2019/10/25/cat/subcat/post-name/amp/`

How can I redirectmatch the old format to the new one with htaccess?

Comment: This seems to have little to do with AMP and more to do with moving parts of the date around in the URL

Comment: Yeah..i'm a little lost to switching the order around in the URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Tried the "Redirection" plugin and eventually figured out this for a solution.

```
Source:
^/([0-9]{4})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+)/amp/$
Target:
https://www.example.com/$1/$4/$5/$2/$3/$6/amp/
```

Change the option in the plugin to Regex.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for sharing. Cheers!!